# Marionette.js behaviors, как привязать метод из behaviors для всех вьюх?

Tags: javascript, marionette.js

Дано:

1. Некий класс расширяющий Marionette.Behavior, например
   MySuperBehavior.
2. Несколько разных классов расширяющих ItemView,
   например TralalaView, Trololoview, и там и там задан соответствующий behavior

Я хочу создать в MySuperBehavior метод, который будет доступен для каждого экземпляра TralalaView и TrololoView, как мне сделать это идеологически верно?

Немного псевдокода иллюстрирующего, что я хочу:

```
 var mySuperBehavior =  Marionette.Behavior.extend({
        awesomeNonStaticMethod: function(){
            console.log(this);
        }
    });
```

Считаем что классы прописаны ок

```
var tralalaView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    behaviors: {
      somebehavior: {
        behaviorClass: MySuperBehavior,
        message: "hello world"
      }
    }
  // Ну и тут что-то происходит
});

var instOfTralala = new tralalaView();
console.log(instOfTralala.awesomeNonStaticMethod()); // Хочу вот так или похожим образом
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал как-то так:

```
var mySuperBehavior =  Marionette.Behavior.extend({

       initialize: function (options, view) {                
            this.view.awesomeNonStaticMethod = this.awesomeNonStaticMethod;
       },

       awesomeNonStaticMethod: function(){
            console.log(this);
       }
    });
```